# Mobile Foundation on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create Mobile Foundation service on Bluemix, but clicking on start server it  shows this can take 10 min to complete but after few minutes it shows an error:

> "Container service: Failed to deploy container."

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem was, it seems to be resolved now.
I've successfully created a Mobile Foundation service instance.

Try again.